# Cannot connect to a SQL database via XAMPP - Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, sqlsrv

I am trying to access a SQL database from my PHP code. I am currently using XAMPP 8.0.6 with PHP 8.0.6. This is also not working on a machine with PHP 7.4.19 and the relevant extensions installed.

Installed drivers / extensions:

- sql-srv: php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
- sql-pdo: php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
- OBDC drivers: 10.0.19041.1

The sqlsrv and sql-pdo are placed correctly in the php.ini. Connecting to the database using the OBDC gui, I get a successful connection.

The code that I am trying to get data from the database with is:

```
      function mssqlConnect(){
        $ServerName = "xxx";
        $ConnectionTimeout = 30;
        $connectionOptions = ["Database"=>"database","UID"=>"user","PWD"=>"password", "LoginTimeout" => $ConnectionTimeout];
        
        $sqlconn = sqlsrv_connect($ServerName,$connectionOptions);
        if( $sqlconn ) {
          echo "Connection established";
        } else {
          echo "Connection could not be established";
          die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
      }
```

When attempting to run this, I get this following message:

```
Connection could not be established. 
Array (
[0] => Array (
[0] => IM006
[SQLSTATE] => IM006
[1] => 0
[code] => 0
[2] =>
[Microsoft]
[ODBC Driver Manager] Driver\'s SQLSetConnectAttr failed
)
[1] => Array (
[0] => 01000
[SQLSTATE] => 01000
[1] => 5701
[code] => 5701
[2] =>
[Microsoft]
[ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]
[SQL Server]Changed database context to \'database\'.
)
[2] => Array (
[0] => 01000
[SQLSTATE] => 01000
[1] => 5703
[code] => 5703
[2] =>
[Microsoft]
[ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]
[SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english.
)
```

It's able to reach out to the database just fine. When I try to use a bogus user/pass I get a 401 error `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'other user'`

A page I found said to disable pooling, I set a ConnectionPooling option in the $conectionOptions array with both a 0 and 1 and am getting the same result. I also tried by changing it via the OBDC GUI to the same result.

I am unable to successfully connect to the database. I also cannot find any related documentation to the error codes that I am receiving. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating `SQL Server` drivers!!

You probably can find those drivers by Googling "`Download ODBC Driver for SQL Server`".
In my case, verion 17 or above fixed the issue.

Also, try the [PDO-SQL-Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-sql-server-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#pdo_sqlsrv-example) example (maybe PDO implementation works).

### Example:

```php
<?php  
function mssqlConnect() {
  $ServerName = "xxx";

  try {  
    $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$ServerName;Database = database", 'user', 'password');   
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );   
  } catch( PDOException $e ) {  
     die( "Connection could not be established - " . $e->getMessage() );   
  } 

  echo "Connection established";
  return $conn;
}

function findEmployee($name) {
  $conn = mssqlConnect();
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');
  if ($stmt->execute(array('name' => $name))) {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      // do something with $row
    }
  } else {
    echo 'Query error - ' . join(' ', $stmt->errorInfo());
  }

  // Close connection which execute created.
  $stmt->closeCursor();
}

?>
```

Comment: Wow this was it. 

I updated the server to version 17 (was on version 11 before) and updated my queries to include the pdo sql drivers. Thank you Top-Master!!

Comment: FWIW, the answer talks about **drivers**, not the server itself. Also, both the PDO API and the procedural one use the same core so whatever works for one should work for the other. You probably got a driver update as a side effect of installing the server update.

Answer (score 0):

try install latest version of ODBC driver

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29895447)